# Laravel 4.1 login route shows blank page

Tags: apache, laravel-4, centos

When I try to open example.com/login it displays a blank page
The routes are working since example.com redirects to example.com/login
and when I add a test route it works fine.

The page is blank and with no console errors and a completely empty html source

So it seems there is a problem with 
`Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');`

I have checked the logs, but they do not show any error related to login page.
Checked logs:
`/var/log/httpd/error_log`
`laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Tried setting permissions for storage and bootstrap/cache. But none of them helped.

OS: CentOS 7
SELinux: Permissive
Laravel : 4.1

Please help and let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Your LoginController@index function is probably not returning anything.